# Is it possible to make an "if" statement affect two separate parts of code?

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to JavaScript and I was wondering if it is possible to make an `if` statement affect two separate parts of code. For example:

```js
console.log(1);
console.log(2);
console.log(3);
```

The code above should print the numbers 1, 2, and then 3 in that order, but I want to add a test to it. If the test passes, all three commands should run, but if it fails only a 2 should be printed. I could add two `if` statements like this:

```js
if (test()) {console.log(1)}
console.log(2);
if (test()) {console.log(3)}
```

My problem with this is the `test()` function is being run twice. Is there a way to only run the test once while preserving the order of the numbers? Sorry if there's an obvious answer and I'm just missing it.

(I should add that this is just an example of 3 events that have to happen in order, so I need an answer that would work not just for printing consecutive numbers but anything situation where you would want 3 things to happen in order.)

Comment: You can create a variable and check its value

Comment: `let t = test(); if (t) ...; if (t) ...;`

Comment: `let cond = test(); if (cond) ... `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is best done by storing the value in a variable that will handle the control flow execution (this variable is known as a flag). You can make it as simple as this:

```
let testResult = test();
if (testResult) {
    console.log(1);
}
console.log(2);
if (testResult) {
    console.log(3);
}
```

This will ensure that if `testResult` is `false` (i.e. `test` returns `false` or a falsy value) then you will only have `2` printed, but if `test` returns true or a truthy value, then `1`, `2`, `3` will all be printed.

If you only want a single `if` statement, then use `if-else` and print `2` in both of them:

```
let testResult = test();
if (testResult) {
    console.log(1);
    console.log(2);
    console.log(3);
} else {
    console.log(2);
}
```

(note you could eliminate the first line in the code block above and just use `if (test())` since you only call `test` once, but I've kept it just so you can see it's usable in many situations).

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I never thought of that. I have to ask is there really no way to write it without using multiple if statements?

Comment: Well to preserve that original order, no - although you could print `2` if test is false, and print `1`, `2`, `3` if test returns true. I'll add that to my answer for you @Druby.

Answer (score 2):

You can try ternary operator!

```
(test()?(event1;event2;event3):(event2))
```

Comment: That's really interesting, I've never heard of those before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So another alternative is to use the flag into the function you can skip heavy calculations or something, the down side of this is if you whant to return `null`

```js
var TheTestFlag = null;
let test = () => {
    if(TheTestFlag === null){
        console.log("Entered into heavy logic");
        //...do some stuff
        // don't return assigne to the flag
        //for exaple if(a>b) TheTestFlag = false;
        TheTestFlag = false;
    }
    //return the flag
    return TheTestFlag;
};
if (test()) {
    console.log(1);
}
console.log(2);
if (test()) {
    console.log(3);
}
```